# tf merge /discard reporting "There are no changes to merge" but tf merge /candidate shows the changeset I want to discard

Tags: merge, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, tfvc

I have a changeset 8889 that I want to remove from the Source Control Merge Wizard in Visual Studio 2017. I actually want to remove several, but I'm starting with this one.

[image: Source Control Merge Wizard shows changeset 8889]

If I proceed with the wizard, there are changes checked out of my target branch. **Ultimately, I don't want to merge these changes ever, and I want to not see changeset 8889 in the wizard dialog.**

When I execute `tf merge /recursive /candidate` in the Visual Studio 2017 command line, I similarly see changeset 8889.

[image: Changeset 8889 in Visual Studio 2017 command line]

However, when I attempt to discard the merge with `tf merge /discard /version:C8889 $/Company/Source/Team/Gordon $/Company/Source/Main/Develop /recursive`, it prints `There are no changes to merge` and the changeset seems to be unaffected. It still shows up in the wizard. **How can I get the changeset to go away?**

We use Azure DevOps, not an on-prem TFS server. I don't know if that makes a difference.

I've looked at the following questions, but to no avail:

- [How to block a changeset from merging in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024919/how-to-block-a-changeset-from-merging-in-tfs)
- [merge /discard reports 'No Pending Changes' when /candidate shows them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897031/merge-discard-reports-no-pending-changes-when-candidate-shows-them)